# How can I replicate crystal graphs in J.Stembridge's paper?

Tags: graphs

I need to include 3 (2-colored) directed graphs at pp.4822 in

John R. Stembridge
A local characterization of simply-laced crystals
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 355 (2003), 4807-4823 
http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2003-355-12/S0002-9947-03-03042-3/

[image]

I first tried Graphviz. For example, the left graph structure is encoded as

```
digraph crystal {
graph [ labelloc = t label = "Crystal graph" ]
B_0_0 [ label="" ]
B_1_0 [ label="" ]
B_1_1 [ label="" ]
B_2_0 [ label="" ]
B_2_1 [ label="" ]
B_3_0 [ label="" ]
B_3_1 [ label="" ]
B_3_2 [ label="" ]
B_4_0 [ label="" ]
B_4_1 [ label="" ]
B_4_2 [ label="" ]
B_5_0 [ label="" ]
B_5_1 [ label="" ]
B_6_0 [ label="" ]
B_6_1 [ label="" ]
B_7_0 [ label="" ]
B_0_0 -> B_1_0 [ label=1 ]
B_0_0 -> B_1_1 [ label=2 ]
B_1_0 -> B_2_0 [ label=2 ]
B_1_1 -> B_2_1 [ label=1 ]
B_2_1 -> B_3_0 [ label=2 ]
B_2_0 -> B_3_1 [ label=2 ]
B_2_1 -> B_3_2 [ label=1 ]
B_3_0 -> B_4_0 [ label=1 ]
B_3_2 -> B_4_0 [ label=2 ]
B_3_1 -> B_4_1 [ label=1 ]
B_3_1 -> B_4_2 [ label=2 ]
B_4_2 -> B_5_0 [ label=1 ]
B_4_1 -> B_5_0 [ label=2 ]
B_4_0 -> B_5_1 [ label=2 ]
B_5_0 -> B_6_0 [ label=1 ]
B_5_1 -> B_6_1 [ label=2 ]
B_6_1 -> B_7_0 [ label=1 ]
B_6_0 -> B_7_0 [ label=2 ]
}
```

But I could not display the result "slimly", "compactly", "minimally" as in Stembridge's paper.

It seems Graphviz approach is not good.
What is a good way to replicate Stembridge's crystal graphs
that can be inserted as figures in a paper?
For example, tikz seems to have nice functions to draw graphs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide image here from this article (it is not reachable for all of us). also provide small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. help us to help you! welcome to tex.se!

Comment: There are a couple of things you could do to help us help you: include a full compilable [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), and include the output you get together with the output you'd like

Comment: I think Graphviz approach is not good. I would like to know the tools suitable for drawing directed graphs in a paper.

Comment: I snipped the image of graphs according to Zarko's advice, thanks.

Comment: When you say graphviz, are you referring to [graphviz.sty](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/graphviz?lang=en) or just using the output of [graphviz the application](https://www.graphviz.org/)? One is a latex frontend to the other.  You could do it by hand in TikZ, but you don't need to

Comment: Thanks for editing. What I meant is the output of graphviz the application. Judging from source codes of other crystal papers on arXiv, tikz seems to be a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

This code hopefully will get you started

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {
    draw, circle, 
    inner sep = 1pt
  },
  thick arrow/.style = {
    ->, -latex, 
    ultra thick
  },
  thin arrow/.style = {
    ->, -stealth', 
  },
  ]

  % node L<i> <j> means <j>-th node of the <i>-th layer 
  \node (L0) {};

  \node[below left = of L0] (L1 0){};
  \node[below right = of L0] (L1 1){};

  \node[below = of L1 0] (L2 0){};
  \node[below = of L1 1] (L2 1){};

  \node[below left = of L2 0] (L3 0){};
  \node[below right = of L2 0] (L3 1){};
  \node[below right = of L2 1] (L3 2){};

  \node[below left = of L3 1] (L4 0){};
  \node[below left = of L3 2] (L4 1){};
  \node[below right = of L3 2] (L4 2){};

  \node[below right = of L4 0] (L5 0){};
  \node[below right = of L4 1] (L5 1){};

  \node[below = of L5 0] (L6 0){};
  \node[below = of L5 1] (L6 1){};

  \node[below right = of L6 0, label = {[below = 5pt]$x$}] (L7){};

 % edges
  \draw[thick arrow] (L0) -- (L1 0);
  \draw[thin arrow] (L0) -- (L1 1);

  \draw[thin arrow] (L1 0) -- (L2 0);
  \draw[thick arrow] (L1 1) -- (L2 1);

  \draw[thick arrow] (L2 0) -- (L3 0);
  \draw[thin arrow] (L2 0) -- (L3 1);
  \draw[thick arrow] (L2 1) -- (L3 2);

  \draw[thin arrow] (L3 0) -- (L4 0);
  \draw[thick arrow] (L3 1) -- (L4 0);
  \draw[thick arrow] (L3 2) -- (L4 1);
  \draw[thin arrow] (L3 2) -- (L4 2);

  \draw[thick arrow] (L4 0) -- (L5 0);
  \draw[thin arrow] (L4 1) -- (L5 1);
  \draw[thick arrow] (L4 2) -- (L5 1);

  \draw[thick arrow] (L5 0) -- (L6 0);
  \draw[thin arrow] (L5 1) -- (L6 1);

  \draw[thin arrow] (L6 0) -- (L7);
  \draw[thick arrow] (L6 1) -- (L7);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a great help for me. Referring to your code, I think I could draw other graphs.